# Getting Error Assertion failure: movie player has wrong activation state (1) even though i use only one movie player

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using Only 1 `MPMoviePlayerController` in ViewController. What i am doing is present a ViewController in which i have a scrollview inside which there are 4 - 5 subviews where user can perform different actions like watching a video in `MPMoviePlayerController`, typing some text, using the stepper control to rate etc.

When the user goes to the VC watches video & comes back on the home VC & again tries to go back this:

```
Getting Error Assertion failure: movie player has wrong activation state (1)
```

And this `Only happens in adhoc build`. When i try to repro it in debug mode i just don't see this error. It's bit confusing.

Take a look at the code below and suggest changes.

I init it like this in a method.

```
     void SomeMethod(){

            this.MoviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController ();
            this.MoviePlayer.View.Frame = new RectangleF (AppConstants.ZeroVal,contentHeight, VIEW_WIDTH, 200);
            this.MoviePlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Default;
            this.MoviePlayer.SourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming;
            this.MoviePlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill;
            this.MoviePlayer.ContentUrl = NSUrl.FromString(_someUrl_);
     }
```

and in a Button's TouchUpInside

```
 btnObj.TouchUpInside+=((ss,ee)=>{
            this.MoviePlayer.View.Hidden = false;
            containerView.Add (this.MoviePlayer.View);
            BtnPlayFeedbackUserRespVideo.Hidden = true;
            this.MoviePlayer.Play ();
           });
```

in the ViewDidLoad

```
public override void ViewDidLoad(){
       // Keyboard popup
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver
            (UIKeyboard.DidShowNotification,KeyBoardUpNotification);

            // Keyboard Down
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver
            (UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification,KeyBoardDownNotification);


            MPMoviePlayerController.Notifications.ObservePlaybackDidFinish(HandleMoviePlayerStoppedPlaying);
            MPMoviePlayerController.Notifications.ObserveWillExitFullscreen (HandleDidExitFullScreen);
            MPMoviePlayerController.Notifications.ObserveWillEnterFullscreen(HandleDidEnterFullScreen);

}



    private void HandleDidExitFullScreen(object ss,NSNotificationEventArgs ee){

        IsPlayingFullScreen = false;
        if (this.MoviePlayer != null) {
            this.MoviePlayer.Pause ();
        }
    }


    private void HandleDidEnterFullScreen(object ss,NSNotificationEventArgs ee){


        IsPlayingFullScreen = true;
        if (this.MoviePlayer != null) {
            this.MoviePlayer.Pause ();
        }
    }


    private void HandleMoviePlayerStoppedPlaying(object ss,MPMoviePlayerFinishedEventArgs ee){ //MPMoviePlayerFinishedEventArgs ee){
    if (this.MoviePlayer != null) {

            if (ee.FinishReason == MPMovieFinishReason.PlaybackEnded || ee.FinishReason == MPMovieFinishReason.UserExited || ee.FinishReason == MPMovieFinishReason.PlaybackError) {
                InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                        if (ReviewState) {
                            if (SelectedLastChallengeForeview != null) {
                                this.MoviePlayer.ContentUrl = NSUrl.FromString (SelectedChallengeForReview.ResponseVideoUrl);
                            } else {
                                if (SelectedChallengeForReview != null) {
                                    this.MoviePlayer.ContentUrl = NSUrl.FromString (SelectedChallengeForReview.ResponseVideoUrl);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            this.MoviePlayer.ContentUrl = NSUrl.FromString(FeedbackToSubmit.ResponseVideoUrl);
                        }

                        this.MoviePlayer.View.Hidden = true;
                        BtnPlayFeedbackUserRespVideo.Hidden = false;
                        this.MoviePlayer.PrepareToPlay();

                });
            }
        }
    }
```

In the view ViewWillDisappear

```
public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);

            if (IsPlayingFullScreen) {
                return;
            }


            if (!IsSubmittingFeedback && !ReviewState) {
                if (this.MoviePlayer != null) {
                    this.MoviePlayer.Stop ();

                }


                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (MPMoviePlayerController.WillEnterFullscreenNotification);
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (MPMoviePlayerController.WillExitFullscreenNotification);
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (MPMoviePlayerController.PlaybackDidFinishNotification);
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (UIKeyboard.DidShowNotification);
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (UIKeyboard.DidHideNotification);



                PopToActivityVC (false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but ran into a similar problem a while back.

Keep in mind that when you create a binary using Ad-Hoc, the app optimisation settings are usually set to high (by default). This can affect the timing of your app. Turn up the optimisation settings for your debug scheme and you should be able to replicate the problem.

Your code looks ok. Am not great at Swift but translating it doesn't turn up any problems.

You should also be vigilant of adding and removing notifications at the correct time. This can also trigger an issue like the one you're seeing.

Comment: This is not swift. It's Xamarin C#. :) What is the ideal time to remove observers ?